# str to bytes in Python3.3

Tags: python, string, unicode, byte, encode

How can I get `b'\xe3\x81\x82'` from `'\xe3\x81\x82'`?

Finally, I want     `u'\u3042'`, which means Japanese letter 'あ',

`b'\xe3\x81\x82'.decode('utf-8')` makes  `u'\u3042'` but

`'\xe3\x81\x82'.decode('utf-8')` causes the following error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

because `b'\xe3\x81\x82'` is bytes and `'\xe3\x81\x82'` is str.

I have DB with data like `'\xe3\x81\x82'`.

Answer (score 4):

If you have bytes disguising as Unicode code points, encode to Latin-1:

```
'\xe3\x81\x82'.encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
```

Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) maps Unicode codepoints one-on-one to bytes:

```
>>> '\xe3\x81\x82'.encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
'あ'
```